# Can I remove `RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make` from my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In the [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) I'm following it tells me to put the following commands in my `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

I understand what all of the lines are doing, except for:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
```

And everything seems to work without it. Can I delete this line from my `Dockerfile`? Will deleting this line cause problems for me down the road? Why do I need anything "python" in this node project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the PR [which added that line](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/pull/218), it seems like it was added to fix an issue with Apple M1 support for the node-gyp package. A later PR [took the line back out](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/pull/212), but that change does not seem to be reflected on the docker website.

That does beg the question of why it breaks on M1, but I don't have an M1 laptop, so I can't answer that.