# Adding python2.7 to docker file with base image as node

Tags: python, node.js, docker

My project package.json has node-sass:"^4.14.1" and I need to containerise it. My application in local works on node: 14.17.4, I cant change any dependencies whatsoever. When I'm trying to do a npm install in dockerfile I'm gettiing can't find python@2.7(node-sass needs py2.7 installed to install itself correctly). Im installing py2.7 but somehow docker is not able to pick it up

```
FROM node:14.17.4-alpine

RUN npm install --python=python2.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY client /app

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin/python27"

RUN npm ci

EXPOSE 7092

CMD ["npm","run","devserver"]
```

It gives me the following error while doing `npm ci` in `docker build .` command

```
#9 34.39 gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
#9 34.39 gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

Probably the path Im setting is wrong, Can someone guide here ?

Comment: To the best of my ability to inspect the `node:14.17.4-alpine` image, it doesn't include Python at all. You will want to `apk add python2` before the `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tripleee is correct. you're declaring an environment variable in your docker container called PYTHONPATH, which shouldn't be needed if python2 is installed properly with `RUN apk add python2`

[relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200635/can-i-remove-run-apk-add-no-cache-python2-g-make-from-my-dockerfile)